# Getting all data using suggest in ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, nosql, search-suggestion

Lets say i have a DB with 2 fields - name and age.

I am using a suggest query for the name, but I would like to get the age in same request.

For example want the next query to return the age as well -

query = {

```
'suggest': {
    'my_suggestion': {
        'text': 'Mark',
        'term': {
            'field': 'name'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try following the docs first https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html

Comment: I have read the docs, I did not find there how to get data from other fields (basically extracting the whole row).

Answer (score 0):

[`Term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html) suggester doesn't support returning of other fields. If it is suitable for your case, you could switch to [`completion`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) suggester, which returns standard `_source` field by default and supports [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html).